# extracting an element node via XPath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

A part of the input xml ist

```
<root>
    <page>1</page>
    <embedded>
        <items>
            <_links>
                    <href>abc</href>
            </_links>
            <parent>null</parent>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <values>
            <data1>
                <locale>DE</locale>
                <scope>null</scope>
                <data>abc</data>
            </data1>
                <data3>
                    <locale>null</locale>
                    <scope>null</scope>
                    <data>producta</data>
                    <links>
                        <download>
                        </download>
                    </links>
                </data3>
                <data4>
                    <locale>null</locale>
                    <scope>null</scope>
                    <data>productc</data>
                </data4>
            </values>
        </items>
    </embedded>
</root>
```

First I saved the element content of data in a Variable (this is important for other steps in my XSLT code.)

```
 <xsl:variable name="content" select="root/embedded/items[position()=$+1]/values/*/data"/>
```

I want to test every data.
I search a way how I can write a condition where I have **just** the content of the data element (for example 'producta') saved in a variable. 
The condition should look if the locale element (preceding-sibling) have the content 'null' and when this condition is true copy the parent-element and the data element.

1. variable content = producta
2. the preceding sibling of producta - locale = null
3. if the condition is true copy the data element and the parent element

The output should look like

```
                    <data3>
                        <data>producta</data>
                    </data3>
                    <data4>  
                        <data>productc</data>
                    </data4>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doens't `items[position()=$+1]` just give a syntax error? Or what is `$+1` supposed to compute? Is there a variable name missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `items[position()=$+1]` is some typo, I assumed it (temporarily) as `items[position()=1]`

Then the expected result can be achieved in XSLT 1.0 as following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="content" 
  select="/root/embedded/items[position()=1]/values/*/data" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$content[preceding-sibling::locale[.= 'null']]">
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9k

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for!